# pyuic4 producing file with SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xff'

Tags: python, qt

**NOTE: This is not the usual 'why is my encoding not set?' question!**

I have a Qt ui file which I am converting for use with PyQt4 using the following command:

`pyuic4 model_importer.ui > model_importer.py`

It runs fine, but when I try to import it as a module, or even run it as a script it fails with the following error:

`File "C:\Users\j\projects\model_importer.py", line 1 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xff' in file C:\Users\j\model_importer.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details`

The following code, with the correct encoding is what is output from pyuic4, and does work if it is pasted into a **new** file. My **original** file is [here](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/efabe15c). This error also occurs when the file is completely empty which leads me to think there is some kind of corruption within the file itself.

Can anyone shed light on this peculiar error?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '.\model_importer.ui'
#
# Created: Thu Mar 12 13:57:45 2015
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_ModelImporterDlg(object):
    def setupUi(self, ModelImporterDlg):
        ModelImporterDlg.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ModelImporterDlg"))
        ModelImporterDlg.resize(722, 223)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(ModelImporterDlg)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(ModelImporterDlg)
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonBox"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.buttonBox, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(ModelImporterDlg)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("accepted()")), ModelImporterDlg.accept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("rejected()")), ModelImporterDlg.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ModelImporterDlg)

    def retranslateUi(self, ModelImporterDlg):
        ModelImporterDlg.setWindowTitle(_translate("ModelImporterDlg", "Model Importer", None))
        self.file_tw.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.file_tw.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("ModelImporterDlg", "Model", None))
        self.file_tw.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("ModelImporterDlg", "Version", None))

import resource_rc
```

Comment: [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was BOM! Apparently set but hidden in Sublime Text 3. Adding `"show_encoding": true` to User settings and then changing the encoding to UTF-8 solved this problem. Thanks @ekhumoro

[image: BOM]

My alternative fix for this is to use `pyuic.py` directly, which doesn't seem to output with BOM:

`python C:\osgeo\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py -o model_importer.py model_importer.ui`